# Pipes to C++ Streams

Tags: c++, ipc, posix, pipe, iostream

is it possible to turn pipes genereated via pipe() on a POSIX-system into std::istreams and std::ostreams?
if yes, how?

i would prefer to use << and >> instead of read() and write()

thanks in advance

Comment: I have never seen someone hyphenate an identifier like that. I thoroughly approve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are non-standard constructors which take file descriptor number or FILE*. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00074.html#a777faeb6849444b4663d1cbe543e1ae3

Comment: __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> buf(pipe, std::ios::in);
 iostream output(&buf);

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/ and http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/

EDIT http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/

I forget which one hosts the latest source, but it's a very good cross-platform IPC library with support for pipes.

It's not actually part of boost but they want (or wanted) it to be.